# Multipolyfit IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to do multivariable non-linear regression with python. Hour, day, and temps are the independent variables, and load is the dependent variable.

I have installed numpy and multipolyfit.

The python code is the following:

```
import numpy, multipolyfit
data=numpy.loadtxt("midatl_combined.txt")
hour=data[:,3]
day=data[:,4]
temps=data[:,5]
load=data[:,6]

a,b,c,d=numpy.polyfit(temps, load, 3)

a=str(round(a,2))
b=str(round(b,2))
c=str(round(c,2))
d=str(round(d,2))

print "load = " +a+" * temp^3 + "  +b+" * temp^2 + "  +c+" * temp + "   +d

a, b, c, d, e=multipolyfit.multipolyfit(hour, day, temps, load, 3)
```

The output is

```
load = -3.91 * temp^3 + 547.89 * temp^2 + -25367.77 * temp + 416600.52
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "midatl.py", line 84, in <module>
    a, b, c, d, e=multipolyfit.multipolyfit(hour, day, temps, load, 3)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multipolyfit-0.0.1-   
py2.7.egg\multipolyfit\
core.py", line 54, in multipolyfit
    num_covariates = xs.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The one-variable regression works fine, but the multi-variable regression does not.Why am I getting this error?

Comment: There ya go, accept if you found my response helpful! Thanks

Comment: Angus Williams, the coefficients I am getting for a degree of 2 are [ 35605.   1314.    497.   -496.    -41.    -45.      1.   -449.     50.      2.
]   Do you know what order these are in (x^2 y^2 x^1...) or (x^2 x^1 x^0)

Comment: I can't see in the documentation which order these should be returned in, rather unhelpfully.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't calling `multipolyfit` in the right way. The docstring suggests that it should be used as `multipolyfit.multipolyfit(xs,y,deg)` where `xs : array_like, shape (M, k)` are your `hour`, `day` and `temps`. This suggests that they need to be passed as a single array, as follows:

```
multipolyfit.multipolyfit(np.vstack((hour,day,temps)).T ,load,3)
```